# Android 5 lockscreen does NOT timeout

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lock-screens, screen, samsung-galaxy-s-5

When I receive notifications, plug in power, or manually turn on my phone display, the lock screen stays on forever (until battery runs out). My display timeout setting is set to 15 seconds (the lowest). The normal display times out correctly, just not the lockscreen.

A month ago I enabled developer mode, but only used it to enable usb debugging and made an adb backup of my phone. The lockscreen still timed out after that and I have made no other modification to the settings since then. The phone has not ever been rooted. Developer mode is currently off. Virus protection is on, and I've only downloaded authorized apps from the store.

I tried turning on/off gestures, smart stay, removing phone from case, cleaning screen, etc. I have no idea what is causing the lock screen to stay on and not timeout.

Samsung Galaxy S5 SM-G900T
android 5.0

Comment: IDK whether this is true but a user in a comment ([here](http://gadgetguideonline.com/galaxys6/samsung-galaxy-s6-online-user-manual/samsung-galaxy-s6-lock-screen/)) mentioned this : *If smart stay is enabled, the lock screen will not turn off as long as you are looking at the screen.* Do you have such setting? Try tweaking it and tell us if it worked.

Comment: I have it off actually. I mentioned this option as 'face detector' in my question. I'll reword now.

Comment: Just now I got a flood of app windows opening into a state I had them in (clock app with schedules I had previously deleted, magically back) days prior to this problem with the lock screen starting. Something screwy is obviously happening here. Anyway to do an android cache reset or w/e. Not a factory reset. Just a system restore kind of thing?

Comment: Depends on whether your recovery supports it: Boot into [recovery mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/recovery-mode/info), see if there's a "wipe cache" option. This is present in all recoveries I've seen – but there are many I've not seen :) Would do exactly what you're asking: Emptying the cache, no data loss.

Comment: Tried just now,  did not fix issue.

Comment: I also tried removing Lookout and Android device manager from the authorized admin list, as they apparently can control how and when the lock screen happens. No fix.